# How to double hop pivot?

Tags: windows, metasploit, tunneling, pivoting

I have a networking routing problem which I am unable to find a solution for:

I have a first machine, 192.168.51.103 (Windows), which is linked to subnet 172.16.51.0/24. To access this subnet, I first compromised 192.168.51.103 and then used the `post/multi/manage/autoroute` metasploit module in combination with `auxiliary/server/socks5` and proxychains binary. Using this method, I was able successfully access the 172.16.51.0-255 subnet from my kali machine.

However, the problem arises when I discover that 172.16.51.109 (Windows), is linked to another subnet, 10.10.11.0/24. There's a machine in the 10.10.11.0/24 that I want to compromise, 10.10.11.117 (Windows). To do so, I have a valid local administrator username and password.

Assuming I want to use a tool that I can only run from my kali machine (192.168.51.30) like `impacket-psexec` or something like that, how I could I manage to access 10.10.11.117 (Windows) from my kali machine (192.168.51.30)? Would the metasploit `autoroute` module do the work or I would need to set up some port forwarding rules?

```
Kali (192.168.51.30) --- 192.168.51.103 --- 172.16.51.0/24
                                            172.16.51.109 --- 10.10.11.0/24
```

Additional information about the machines:

```
192.168.51.103(Windows): I have a high-integrity meterpreter session on it.
172.16.51.109(Windows): I have a high-integrity meterpreter session on it.
10.10.11.117(Windows): It has ports 135, 139, 445, 3389 and 5985 opened.
```